# iPhone Copying plist files to bundle resources and target

Tags: iphone, info.plist

I have 3 different targets fro my project.

I am not sure, if I should copy all the info plist files of the corresponding targets in their bundle resources. 
Should the plist files be copied in the targets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think so.

You need to copy only the xib files and image files etc. into the resources. e.g. .h files are not copied. but .m files are.